# Storing app wide instance. Static field vs pass instance as argument

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have an instance of a class which i need access to in many different places of my app. I have come up with three solutions so far

1. Passing the instance as an argument in every class of the app
2. Making a top level Provider above the MaterialApp-widget that exposes the instance to every method that has access to the app's context
3. Storing the instance in a static field

Which way is the best performance wise? Will the Flutter-framework ever discard the instance stored in the static field?

Comment: Hi There. Flutter already works on a provider type framework with things like `Navigator` and `MediaQuery`. Save yourselves some headache (due to obsessing over performance) and make your code cleaner for everyone to understand and debug by following the same pattern.

Comment: @NisanthReddy, I think that the question is not about the performance but how to avoid coupled the app with a specific implementation of the class. This problem was solved a lot of times ago with the DI pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Which way is the best performance wise? Will the Flutter-framework ever discard the instance stored in the static field?

In this case, I like to use the DI framework like [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

With the DI you can specify what is the object that you want and you can have it in your Wiget or Component, without coupled it with the specific implementation.

Use the get started guide to see how it is simple to use and what are the benefits.

[Get Started](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it#getting-started)

### Suggestion

I suggest wrapping the library in one component inside your app, with the only motivation that with your own wrapper around the DI library you avoid to coupled all the app with the `get_it`, and you can change it easily in the future if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the performance, but the second option (Provider way) is what I am using in my projects and that's even a recommended approach (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options#provider).

> Passing the instance as an argument in every class of the app

This could lead to a very cumbersome code, every constructor would be cluttered by the same property passing all the way down to the Widget tree - not a Flutter way at all, that's why `InheritedWidget` was introduced some time ago, and later - Provider.

> Storing the instance in a static field

It depends. E.g. it is ok to store all the colour constants inside a class having static fields - that's just convenient to access them everywhere. This option could also work in your case (not sure about the size and the amount of information stored in that class instance), but implementing your class as a Singleton would probably make more sense than storing the whole instance in a static field.